# How do you integrate fortran code with a java gui?

Tags: java, user-interface, fortran

I have a fortran program that accepts input via a file (*.dat or whatever).

I'm planning to make a GUI (probably using SWT) that would construct the input file based on user input (through forms: textboxes, drop downs, etc).

The problem is, I've never done this before. Is there any standard way to go about this? I'm pretty sure a lot of people have done this (based on google searches), I just have not seen a standard approach for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the feeling you're under the impression that you cannot make a GUI in Fortran, no?

So, here are a few links to try to shake that one ...

[Compaq Visual Fortran: A Guide to Creating Windows Applications](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Compaq-Visual-Fortran-Creating-Applications/dp/1555582494)
[Winteracter](http://www.winteracter.com/)
[GINO](http://www.gino-graphics.com/)

And M.S.B. already mentioned my personal favourite, DISLIN.

(I'm sure there are others as well, but these are the first that come to mind).

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at gtk-fortran:
https://github.com/vmagnin/gtk-fortran/wiki

> The gtk-fortran project aims to offer scientists programming in
> Fortran a cross-platform library to build Graphical User Interfaces
> (GUI), licensed under GNU GPL 3. Gtk-fortran is a partial GTK /
> Fortran binding 100% written in Fortran, thanks to the ISO_C_BINDING
> module for interoperability between C and Fortran, which is a part of
> the Fortran 2003 standard. It offers interfaces to around 10000 GTK
> functions (GTK, GDK, GdkPixbuf, Cairo, Pango, ATK, GLib, GObject,
> GIO).
>
> Note that gtk-fortran goes beyond programming GUI: GTK includes the
> crossplatform GLib library which offers a lot of generic functions
> (regular expressions, random numbers, hash, strings, input/output...),
> and gtk-fortran offers also an interface to PLplot.
>
> Although mainly developed under Linux, you can easily use it under
> Windows via MSYS2. It runs also under UNIX systems like BSD, macOS and
> Raspbian on the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

If you are now beginning with Java, I recommend that you use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) for the development. Netbeans provides a form designer that will make your life easier (uses Swing and not SWT). When you have your file ready, you can start the Fortran process with [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me somewhere! Based on the docs you pointed me to, I first have to compile my fortran code into an executable then have ProcessBuilder call it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know about it, it is possible to construct a GUI with Fortran code, e.g., using the DISLIN graphics library.